# Google Map creates line cut offs with a large number of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Map API and Fusion Tables to render about 14,000 points on the map. The issue I'm coming across is that certain markers on the map are being "cut off" or not being rendered on the map.

[image: Google Map Display Error]

Here is another image that shows the markers:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to render the map:

```js
function initialize() {
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
  if (isMobile) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
  }

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

  mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '90%';
  mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.065686198553315, -89.44005000024413),
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 16,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "col0",
      from: "1Zj0wH--IXepoejLJuomECPcGpQmaCfu_dCkdQUEz",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 3,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  if (isMobile) {
    var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
    var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
    var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
    legend.style.display = 'none';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
    legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 90%; height: 530px;"></div>
```

Has anyone else ran into an issue like this?

Comment: I also experience this, but if you try changing its zoom level it load the markers correctly. Note: The Fusion Tables layer is Experimental, we might experience this kind of behavior. You can try using [Grid-based Clustering, Distance-based Clustering, Viewport Marker Management, Fusion Tables, MarkerClusterer, MarkerManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)  to display a large number of locations or markers.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Rebot, I was able to get around by reducing it to closer to 12,000. If I come across this again I will give those a try.